# remove wordpress audio shortcode with preg_replace

Tags: php, regex

I want remove all `<audio>` shortcode in my post with `preg_replace`, but that dosnt work for me:

```
$content = preg_replace('#<audio>(.*?)</audio>#', '', $content);
```

Comment: Please post some example content.

Comment: <audio class="wp-audio-shortcode" id="audio-1361-3" preload="none" style="width: 100%;" controls="controls"><source type="audio/mpeg" src="example.com/.mp3" data-wpel-link="internal">example.com/.mp3</a></audio>

Comment: `'#<audio>.*?</audio>#s'`

Answer (score -1):

Assuming there I will no newline character in between, Below Regex will work for you.

```
  <audio.*?<\/audio>
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qObVyU/1)

Comment: thanks, i put your code but dosnt work for me, audio code not replace

Comment: can you share the $content value?

Comment: <?php 
$content = get_the_content();
$content = preg_replace('#<audio.*?<\/audio>#', '', $content);  
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
$content = str_replace(']]>', ']]>', $content);
echo $content;
?>

Comment: why are you using # in your regex? Refer [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to know how to use `preg_replace`

Comment: i remove # and test again this code: $content = preg_replace('<audio.*?<\/audio>', '', $content);   and all content of post removed!

Comment: k can you get the value of $content and paste it in the demo link in my answer and check how regex matching ?

Comment: i tested my value with your demo and work correctly but copy in function.php dosnt work

Comment: I’m not familiar with PHP, but the reference link shows / before and after the regex. may try like this `/<audio.*?<\/audio>/`